# Can we pass tablelayout to another fragment using bundle or any other way?

Tags: android, android-studio

How to pass tablelayout to another fragment using bundle or any other way?

I have a tablelyout in which rows are created dynamically.  I want dynamically created rows to be passed to other fragment.

Answer (score 2):

Well you don't want to pass the layout itself to the next fragment, but rather the data that you used to create those rows!

If you share the content, including your data and how you "dynamically create the rows", we can provide more detailed answers.

If you use  shared view models for example, there is no need to pass anything. Both fragments can access the same data.